# Download 1 days azure blob file python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

***Requirement:***

Files are being uploaded into azure container from various machines. Need to write a python script to download one day's file from azure container which will be scheduled daily.

**Code:**

```
import datetime
import os
import pytz

from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, ContainerClient

utc=pytz.UTC
container_connection_string ="CONNECTION_STRING"
container_service_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=container_connection_string, container_name="CONTAINER_NAME")

date_folder = start_time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
base_path = r"DOWNLOAD_PATH"
count = 0
threshold_time = utc.localize(start_time  - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))
blob_list = container_service_client.list_blobs()

if not os.path.exists("{}\{}".format(base_path, date_folder)):
    os.makedirs("{}\{}".format(base_path, date_folder))
print("Starting")

for ind, blob in enumerate(blob_list):
    if threshold_time < blob.last_modified:
        count += 1
        print(count, blob.name)
        blob_name = blob.name       
        blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=container_connection_string, container_name="CONTAINER_NAME", blob_name=blob_name)
        with open("{}\{}\{}".format(base_path, date_folder, blob_name), "wb") as my_blob:
            blob_data = blob.download_blob()
            blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
```

**Problem:**

The above script iterates through all the blob in the container and checkeds if the blobs are less than one day and downloads them if they are. Since daily 15,000+ file are being uploaded in the blob traversing through them to identify today file are very time consuming and downloading blobs take a lot of time.

Comment: Is there any way you can control the name of the files that are being uploaded or the location where they are being uploaded?

Comment: and/or each time you write to blob storage, write also something in table storage and query that instead to retrieve the list of files to download.

Comment: Great idea @CSharpRocks! Have the partition key as reverse ticks with day based precision so that newer entries are always on top.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have no control over the naming of the file since it is a client system. "Have the partition key as reverse ticks" i don't understand this can you explain.

Comment: @CSharpRocks that was a good idea but the current system can not be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current approach, I believe there's no other way than to enumerate the blobs and filter on the client side to find the matching blobs.

---

However I do have an alternate solution. It's a bit convoluted solution but I thought I would propose nonetheless :).

Essentially the solution involves making use of [`Azure Event Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage) and invoke an Azure Function on `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated` event which gets fired when a blob is created or replaced. This Azure Function will copy the blob to a different blob container. Now for each day a new blob container will be created and this blob container will hold blobs only for just that day. This makes iterating over blobs much easier.

Comment: Thanks this approach looks like a good way to get one days worth files.

Comment: Awesome! I would be curious to know how the implementation worked out for you.

Comment: I will implement this and let you know